# Error when plotting on Kaggle using Seaborn. Error says I have categorical data even my data is int64

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn, kaggle

I was working with Banking marketing data set from Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/janiobachmann/bank-marketing-dataset

I want to plot the kdeplot for numerical columns, filter by `deposit`. Every numerical columns work fine, except for `pdays` and `previous` columns.

Specifically, when I plot those 2 columns with `'deposit' == 'yes'`, it is alright. But when I plot those 2 with `'deposit' == 'no'`, it says my data is categorical column so it cannot be done. All of this works with with my Jupyter Notebook.

Please see some screenshots for this problem:
['deposit'=='yes' works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQT8z.png)

['deposit'=='no' says i have categorical columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZPV1.png)

[more on this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iuDt.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the second screenshot you are actually trying a `distplot`. This function needs numerical data and not categorical data.

Edit:

Quite a few entries in that column have value `-1`. Although numerical, it is actually a hack to use a `NaN` in an integer column if I understand correctly.

If I replace them and drop them I do get a proper output:

`sns.kdeplot(df[df['deposit']=='no']['pdays'].replace(-1, np.nan).dropna())`

[image]

Note that since `pandas` `0.24.0` there is support for `<NA>` entries in an integer column through the use of the new `Int64`: ["Nullable integer data type"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html).

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. Whatever plot I use (kdeplot or distplot), they both show errors. I'm pretty sure that columns "pdays" is already numerical. More over, I can plot that column when I filter 'deposit' == 'yes', it works. You can my notebook here: https://www.kaggle.com/kristrng/bank-marketing-eda?scriptVersionId=32386426